# 500 (Internal Server Error) when using ajax in Joomla?

Tags: joomla2.5

I wanna using Ajax at front-end joomla site
I have found and tried some code about call ajax in Joomla! but unfortunately It don't run.
Here is my code:

File : components/com_headattack/views/headattackinfo/tmpl/default.php

```
$("#select-filter1").selectbox({
        onChange: function (val, inst) {

            $('#select-filter2').remove();
            $.post("index.php?option=com_headattack&task=filter1_click&format=raw",
                {
                    elementId : "select-filter1",
                    selectedValue : val
                },
                function(data,status){
                    $('#select_filter_div2').html(data);
                }
            );
        }
    });
```

File : components/com_headattack/controllers/headattackinfo.php

```
public function filter1_click(){
    return "test";
}
```

When I run my site and click select-filter1(combobox) so javascript throw a message :  500 (Internal Server Error)

Please help me to solve my problem :(

Answer (score 1):

Your task currently maps to the main controller in the component: `components/com_headattack/controller.php`

To have the task run in that controller, you should call `task=headattackinfo.filter1_click` (the controller, a period, then the function name).

The full url would look like this:

`index.php?option=com_headattack&task=headattackinfo.filter1_click&format=raw`